# Factional Scaling Shrinks Window But Enlarges Shell - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, display-resolution, scaling

I would like to use (fractional) scaling on my Ubuntu 20.04.5 machine but currently it seems to work not as intended.

When I apply 200% scaling the size of windows does not change while for example the dock has doubles size. So for 200% it seems like the scaling works, but only for the shell. Down below I added a screenshot of this setting.

When I apply fractional scaling (e.g. 150%) windows get smaller (so they are scaled-down) and the shell gets larger. Down below I added a screenshot of this setting.

I would love to have the possibility to scale both, windows and shell to 125% or 150%.

Note: I tried Ubuntu 20.04.5 on a live USB stick and there fractional scaling works as intended for all settings (125%, 150%, 175% and 200%).

**100% Scaling:**
[image: Desktop with terminal on 100% scaling]
**150% Scaling:**
[image: Desktop with terminal on 150% scaling]
**200% Scaling:**
[image: Desktop with terminal on 200% scaling]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with the following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "[{'Gdk/WindowScalingFactor', <2>}]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
```

I am not sure why this solves the problem and why this problem appears, but if you run across this problem the commands above might solve your problem.